# Navigate to the current screen within same data structure

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

[image]

I am facing a problem, in my data structure, parent has child and sub-child without stoping. 
Screen A, Screen B, Screen C, Screen n, are the same so **I want to reuse Screen A to render parent, child, sub-child, n-sub-child.**

navigate: Screen A-> Screen B -> Screen C -> ... Screen n-1 -> Screen n

goBack: Screen n-1 -> Screen n -> ... Screen C -> Screen B -> Screen A

**How to do that?**

I know that I can push parent to stack (use reducer) when i clicked (navigate) on to re-render current screen and pop when I goBack. But this way doesn't have navigation slide effect.

Comment: Reuse the same screen, push new data to state.

Comment: react-navigation prevent navigating from screen A to screen A.

Comment: Do not navigate just refresh the page with new data.

Comment: Then, changing screen doesn't have slide effect.